# Proving the summation of a double factorial infinite series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, factorial

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{n}((2n-1)!!)^2}{(2n)! (2^{2n})} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}  $$

I came across this summation through some other work, came across the solution as part of a function, but I was curious as to how you would solve this in a more traditional sense.

I do know it's related to the golden ratio if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\dfrac{(-1)^{n}((2n-1)!!)^2}{(2n)! (2^{2n})} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}
$

Since

$\begin{array}\\
(2n-1)!!
&=\prod_{k=1}^n (2k-1)\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^n (2k-1)\prod_{k=1}^n (2k)}{\prod_{k=1}^n (2k)}\\
&=\dfrac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}\\
\end{array}
$

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\dfrac{(-1)^{n}((2n-1)!!)^2}{(2n)! (2^{2n})} 
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\dfrac{(-1)^{n}(\dfrac{(2n)!}{2^nn!})^2}{(2n)! (2^{2n})} \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\dfrac{(-1)^{n}((2n)!)^2}{(2^nn!)^2(2n)! (2^{2n})} \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\dfrac{(-1)^{n}(2n)!}{(n!)^2 (2^{4n})} \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{ (2^{4n})} \binom{2n}{n}\\
\end{array}
$

So look at
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }x^n\binom{2n}{n}
$
and you will get your answer.